# HANA DB get current user id login?

Tags: sql, database, hana

I want to get current user using SQL in hana.

These return a low level system ids. What I want is the user logged in.

```
SELECT current_user  FROM DUMMY;
SELECT session_user  FROM DUMMY;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do it. There are other KEYs you can try but this one seems to work.

```
SELECT value as cur_user 
FROM M_SESSION_CONTEXT 
WHERE connection_id=current_connection and KEY ='APPLICATIONUSER' ;
```

Comment: This gives you the operating system user of the process that is running the statement against the DB. The HANA JDBC/ODBC driver fill that automatically. However, if the application has its own user management, this might be different. I recommend being careful what conclusions get drawn from this.

Comment: The os user is what i'm after, i'm not using JDBC / ODBC as far as I know , i'm using webide/SQlscript/dbx/XS. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select 
    "UserCode" , "WinUsrName",
    ( select case when "Action" = 'I' then 'OPEN' when "Action" = 'O' then 'CLOSED' end 
      from USR5 r1
      where r1."UserCode" = r."UserCode" and r1."Date" = r."Date" and r1."Time" = Max(r."Time")
    ) "Login Status"
    ,"Date", "ClientName", Max(r."Time") "Login Time"
  from USR5 r 
  where 
     "ProcName" = 'SAP Business One.exe'  
     and TO_VARCHAR(r."Date",'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_VARCHAR(NOW(),'YYYY-MM-DD')
  group by
     "UserCode" , "WinUsrName",  "Date", "ClientName"
  having 
     MAX("Time") = Max(r."Time")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This seems to do the job:

```
SELECT T0."USERID"
    FROM "OUSR" T0
    INNER JOIN "USR5" T1 
        ON T0."USER_CODE" = T1."UserCode"
    WHERE
        T1."SessionID" = CURRENT_CONNECTION;
```

Of course it works only when used inside B1 session (Query Generator/Preview, DI API etc.). It doesn't work in HANA Studio because there is no B1 user logged in that session.